# v-i characteristics of reverse conducting thyristor

Tags: power-electronics, thyristor

May I know how does a reverse conducting thyristor work and its v-i characteristic? 
I have been searching all over the internet and libraries but the information about RCT is very limited.
To my understanding, RCT has the same characteristics with SCR except in reverse blocking mode, where SCR blocks reverse current but RCT allows current to flow in reverse direction. 
Please correct me if I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Google "RCT thyristor curve".

Comment: Do research before posting and learn how to find things

Answer (score 0):

You are completely right. The RCT is a normal Thyristor with an integrated freewheeling diode.

The reverse conducting thyristor (RCT) is differentiating itself from the normal high power thyristor by having an integrated reverse diode. Because of the reverse diode this thyristor is not capable of reverse blocking.

These devices are advantageous where a reverse or freewheel diode must be used. Because the SCR and diode never conduct at the same time they do not produce heat simultaneously and can easily be integrated and cooled together.

Reverse conducting thyristors are often used in frequency changers and inverters.

This information can be found on:

http://new.abb.com/semiconductors/thyristors/reverse-conducting-thyristors-(rct)

An example RCT can also be found on the abb website. The datasheet presented there shows all the properties of an RCT.

https://library.e.abb.com/public/3779f3b70d6d8facc1257ad400499879/5STR_03T2040.pdf